# How can I prove my competence without working for free?

Tags: freelance-websites

I want to work online. I've tried freelancer.com, but most of the buyers seem fake. At first, they talk as if they'd like to give you projects, but they have to test you and ask other questions or give other tasks. After completing these tasks, they become invisible or become blocked by freelancer.com as fake accounts.

How can I avoid this?   Do all freelancing sites suffer from this?

Comment: Hi Tech Geek, welcome to Freelancing.SE! This question is extremely low in quality, and will likely solicit nothing but opinion, which doesn't work well for Q&A sites. Please [edit] your question to add more details, such as what you are looking for specifically, what ones you have tried, expectations, etc.

Comment: @CanadianLuke Thank you sir for your advice.I just edited my question.I tried my good to explain what is my question.

Comment: Yes, there are many. Just type "freelancing" into google and pick top 5 results.

Comment: @PeterMV Yes, I already tried that.I found out freelancer.com from the Google.Here on this site many experts are here,so I thought they help me with this.

Comment: related: [how can i measure the credibility of a freelancing website](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/544/how-can-i-measure-the-credibility-of-a-freelancing-website)

Comment: When you say "I want to work online", do you mean you want to "find work online"? These do not mean the same things.

Comment: @TechGeek Check this out http://gyantastic.com/best-freelance-websites/. I'd skip Freelancer.com and stick to odesk or elance. As I remember they both offer work by hour + escrow.

Comment: The answer is simple. Avoid working with clients who don't have lots of good feedbacks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though we admittedly haven't been freelancing that long, we have never run into this sort of a problem :(  After setting up profiles on freelancer, freelance, elance and odesk, I have to say that I favor elance greatly.  They don't freak out when you put a link to your portfolio, they facilitate smooth communication, they secure up front payments for non-hourly work (we work on a project per project basis) and they paid out easily to our bank account.

I however will also say we are somewhat selective in what we bid for.  We only bid on projects that are clearly and professionally written.  If the person listing the job can't bother to use punctuation, or makes more than a couple typos, it's hard to take them seriously.  We also don't bid on jobs that are very vague, or jobs that seem shifty.

Best of luck with your freelancing... defiantly check out elance.com we've had a lot of luck there!